# How to convert Windows newlines to Unix newlines when cutting and pasting into Putty window?

Tags: putty, escape-characters

Working on Windows XP Notepad++ with Windows line endings.

When copying and pasting multiple lines into Putty window (connected to Ubuntu machine), it sends weird control characters.

How to convert the pasted text to Unix newlines? What setting should I have for emulation mode?

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ can convert line endings:
[image]

Comment: A good idea, but it didn't work. Still sending weird control characters.

Comment: I'd say that the problem isn't `EOL` characters, then.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I figured out that it's the tabs at the beginning of the lines (from Ruby). Is there a way to replace the tabs with spaces in Putty? I don't want to change the files...

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, though I could easily be wrong.